# && operator doesn't work in Swift3

Tags: swift, binary-operators

I am using Objective-C TextFieldValidator(https://github.com/dhawaldawar/TextFieldValidator) custom class for validating textfields in my app, which have a function which validates regex on it:

```
 -(BOOL)validate{
    if(isMandatory){
        if([self.text length]==0){
            [self showErrorIconForMsg:strLengthValidationMsg];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<[arrRegx count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *dic=[arrRegx objectAtIndex:i];
        if([dic objectForKey:@"confirm"]){
            TextFieldValidator *txtConfirm=[dic objectForKey:@"confirm"];
            if(![txtConfirm.text isEqualToString:self.text]){
                [self showErrorIconForMsg:[dic objectForKey:@"msg"]];
                return NO;
            }
        }else if(![[dic objectForKey:@"regx"] isEqualToString:@""] && [self.text length]!=0 && ![self validateString:self.text withRegex:[dic objectForKey:@"regx"]]){
            [self showErrorIconForMsg:[dic objectForKey:@"msg"]];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    self.rightView=nil;

    return YES;
}
```

Now in my UIViewController I am using the following `if` statement to validate all my textfields inherited from this custom TextFieldValidator in my register form:

```
tfFirstName.isMandatory = true
tfLastName.isMandatory = true

if (tfFirstName.validate() && tfLastName.validate()){
   return true
}else{
   return false
}
```

`tfLastName` field is blank, but it seems like `if` statement calls only `tfFirstName.validate()` and always return `true`, *i.e.* `&&` operator is not working here. **In Objective-C && works fine**, but in Swift 3 it's not. Why is the `&&` operator not working here and what's the solution?

Comment: Please share validate() function

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: `tfLastName.validate()` will only be called if `tfFirstName.validate()` is true. This whole `if` will only return true if both calls to `validate` are true. How do you know that both calls to `validate` are not being made? Are you sure that `tfLastName` doesn't reference the same text field as `tfFirstName`?

Comment: It's never the fault of the language. It is always your own code.

Comment: @Palle
I have tested the same code in Objective-C, and its working. I am sure there is some issue in Swift3 syntax. Why don't you try something similar yourself and suggest me the solution.

Comment: @rmaddy
Can you try the code now and tell me the solution?

Comment: Your validate function returns true if `textfield.text` is `nil` – not sure if that can actually happen since the default value (according to the docs) is `""` – Try `return (textfield.text?.characters.count ?? 0) > 0` instead

Comment: You can also add `print(textfield.text?.characters.count)` to the validate function in order to check if it is called once or twice (or use the debugger and set a breakpoint)

Comment: You can see in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/iOS90APIDiffs/Swift/UIKit.html the text of UITextfield changed to being optional.  It is indeed now nil upon creation.  Your problem is that you return YES when self.text == nil

Answer (score 0):

When text is nil, your validate() function returns YES.  In swift, UITextfield.text can produce a nil value.  Change the first part of your validate function to something like...

```
    if(isMandatory){
        if(self.text == nil || [self.text length]==0){
            [self showErrorIconForMsg:strLengthValidationMsg];
            return NO;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I fix my problem by modifying my code as follows:

```
let isValidFirstName = tfFirstName.validate()
let isValidLastName = tfLastName.validate()
if (isValidFirstName && isValidLastName)){
   return true
}else{
   return false
}
```

Comment: If this code fixes your issue then using `if validate(tfFirstName) && validate(tfLastName) {` will also work.

Comment: In addition, this does not compile (mismatched parentheses), so it *cannot* be your real code.

Comment: @rmaddy: Have you tried recreating my problem, before downvoting or commenting? I am not posting my queries here for getting downvotes, instead I am seriously getting this issue. Try this problem atleast once and then react.

Comment: @MS_iOS Don't make assumptions about who down votes because it wasn't me.

Answer (score -1):

Please review your code, && is working as expected..

```
func validate(_ textfield:UITextField) -> Bool{
    if textfield.text?.characters.count == 0{
        return false
    }else{
        return true
    }
}

func testValidate(){

    let tfFirstName = UITextField()
    tfFirstName.text = "fhgghh"

    let tfLastName = UITextField()
    tfLastName.text = ""

if (validate(tfFirstName) && validate(tfLastName)){
        NSLog("true")
    }else{
        NSLog("false")
    }
}

testValidate()
```

console:: 
2017-09-18 11:54:08.796 MyPlayground2[22908:2591237] **false**

Comment: Stating that you cannot reproduce the problem described in the question is not an answer. (From https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277924/1187415)

Comment: before i answer question sample was different, and now is different.. Coming to your reply, "is not an answer" will apply to all the problems.. if you hit negative to answer who are trying to help.. there wont be any helpers.. don't discourage..